# Multi-page silverlight app

Tags: silverlight

I'm following a small tutorial on how to switch pages in Silverlight. It can be found here:

http://jesseliberty.com/2008/05/31/multi-page-applications-in-silverlight/
It's slightly older, but everything worked.

The technique used here is to have a seperate page with a "Navigator function". If you're on Page1, you use something like this:

```
PageSwitcher ps = this.Parent as PageSwitcher;
ps.Navigate(new Page2());
```

With Navigate being the only function in PageSwitcher:

```
public void Navigate(UserControl nextPage) {
    this.Content = nextPage;
}
```

Still, the way this is handled seems kind of odd. I'm still wondering what the difference is between adding a new User Control and Page. I've tried adding them both, they very much seem the same.

It seems like this is just using a hidden page to engineer the switching between the public pages. This seems somehow over the top to me. Is there an other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the difference between [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and UserControl is that Page has some Navigation methods like NavigationService.

For another way, check out Caliburn Micro's [Screens and Conductors](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation).  It lets you do some advanced navigation stuff with little effort, check out the sample, HelloScreens.  It adds life-cycle to your Screens.  Also the ability to know when the view's been bound and nice stuff like that.

Comment: @Derek_Beattie: I've had a look at it, tried some examples and I find it Caliburn to be complicated as all hell. The tutorials don't help at all. Often I'm wondering when something was introduced or whether or not I need to add something to the code or if it's just there to reference the source. It really feels like this project assumes you're an expert with years and years of experience.

Comment: You can still use the Navigation stuff and use something like MVVM Light messenger as a way to tell the NavigationFrame to navigate to another page.  CM has a bit of a curve I suppose, I think what they've done is brilliant.  Nothing easier than naming a content control as x:Name="ActiveItem" and letting CM do the rest.

Comment: @Derek_Beattie: During my search, I noticed several of the components used are now no longer in the main Silverlight install but part of a separate toolkit. Gonna see tomorrow if that helps any.